# performance for node.js which one better multiple class instance or function call

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, error-handling

I have implement logger in my project so but I have don't know about which way good to implement

Criteria :

1) Huge traffic for project

2) every route - payload and added some parameter in logger

**Example**

```
class Logger {
    constructor (x, y) {
        this.xx = x;
        this.yy = y;
    }

    updatexy (x, y) {
        this.xx = x;
        this.yy = y;
    }
}
```

1) create multiple instance of class and use it.

```
let create = new Logger('z','f');
```

2) create function in class and use it.
(one time created object )

```
let create = new Logger('z','f');
create.updatexy('x','y');
```

what's main different any performance problem.

Comment: without create new object may be possibility to next call value will be change bcz node work asynchronous